# wiscp connection issue with cloudera virtual machine

Tags: linux, hadoop, cloudera

I need to copy from windows to cloudera virtual machine.
I am getting below error:

```
The server rejected SFTP connection, but it listens for FTP connections.
Did you want to use FTP protocol instead of SFTP? Prefer using encryption.
```

I read some link and they are suggestin open port 22. Could any one please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: This question looks off-topic and duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242120/winscp-the-server-rejected-sftp-connection-but-it-listens-for-ftp

Comment: ther is  not mentioned how to open port 22..